# Determining the topic of a conversation programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc, chatbot

This is probably an extremely difficult question to answer, but here is my question anyway.

I am wondering what the best method is for determining the topic of a conversation. The conversation takes place over IRC. I have written chatbots in the past that have interpreted the topic pretty well, but not as accurately as I would like.

In the past I have had to make lists of common words such as "the" and "a" then filter them from the topic array. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it though.

I am wondering if there is a frequency algorithm of some sort that will allow me to work out what word is the current topic of conversation.

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the chat topic happens to be the word "the", you'd be kinda screwed, wouldn't you?

Comment: @cHao Exactly. That's why I am looking for a solution that will return the actual topic. Maybe it turns out that the topic 60% of the time is the 8th most used word. So you should use that rather than the 1st most used one. I have no idea. Thats why I am asking ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called [Zipf's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law).
It could only accurately be applied to text written by a human, and it would have to have some length to it.

The result of running a text through such an algorithm would be a set of keywords (5%-7% of the original text) which closely describe the topic of the text.

Comment: This may cause my brain to fall out of my head. But seems to the be the exact thing I am looking for. I am sure you know what IRC messages are like though. Short and usually not very coherent. Maybe I could combine the last 10 messages or so and run them through something like this...

Comment: Yes, combining is better for analyzing the topic of the whole conversation. I'm pretty sure it will be inaccurate though if there are multiple topics discussed.

Comment: I am sure it will. But any degree of accuracy is better than none. In the past it has been my bots vague accuracy that has made it hilarious. Thank you for this. You have put me on the right track with the idea for samples made of combined messages and using things such as Zipf's Law to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

Natural Language Processing can be very difficult, but you can still get some results with just fundamentals. Daniel Gabriel's suggestion to use Zipf's Law is a good one.

An overview book like Manning and Schütze's [*Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/) may be helpful - it explains many common techniques, and will point you towards more specialized resources.

(Their [*Introduction to Information Retrieval*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) is excellent, too, and has a free PDF on the site.)

Comment: Thanks for this, great answer! I have already implemented something that is similar to Zipf's Law in my bot but I am sure this will help people in the future. Thank you!